# Webform address killing ajax?

Tags: webforms

How do I attach an Ajax behavior to my `country` field (that already has a dropdown behavior).

I have a simple form defined using the webform module.
[image]

In an implementation of `hook_webform_alter` I have the following code that works...

```
$form['elements']['business_e_mail']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'opt-in-wrapper',
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE, 
    'event' => 'change',
  ];
```

However, if I attempt to attach the #ajax behavior to the country field which is really what I need, I get no response. (e.g., the ajax callback is not called)

Code that does not work

```
$form['elements']['country_code']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'opt-in-wrapper',
    'disable-refocus' => FALSE,
    'event' => 'change',
  ];
```

The only seemingly relevent difference between the two fields is that the working field is a simple email address.

The country_code is an address field that also has a behavior attached to it (e.g., it is a dropdown.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What does the unaltered `$form['elements']['country_code']` look like in the form definition? You may need to attach the `#ajax` to a child of that.

Comment: @jaypan Thanks for jumping into this one... 
The form is pretty much boilerplate from the webform module. 

`
country_code [
  #type
  #title
  #webform_key
  #webform_plugin_id
 ...
`

Interesting idea you've got... not sure how effective it will be because I need to find an element that changes - right?

Comment: I would need to find a child that is modified, or maybe not? 

`country_code [
  #title 
  #webform_key
  #country_code__options
]`

Comment: I don't use webform myself. But form elements in Drupal often have children form elements, and you need to attach the #ajax to the actual form element (select, input) as it won't work when attaching it to a parent. This indicates to me that you've attached it to a parent, not the child.